# Make Google Meet confirm before leaving page?

Tags: google-meet

I spend a good part of my day in meetings in Google Meet (to be clear, meet.google.com). Periodically, I accidentally hit refresh or close the wrong browser tab, and it's the Meet tab that I'm closing, which of course means that I'm accidentally leaving the meeting.

Web pages have a basic function that enables the browser to ask "Are you sure you want to leave?" or similar question. Is possible to enable this option via Meet settings or via other browser settings? If not, then can this be added via extension (though lower preference for this option)?

Comment: This is about programming. Please read the last two sentences above. This can apply to any web app. Please reopen.

Comment: Please explain how those sentences are related to programming. Please show what programming language you are using, what you have tried, and what specific part you are stuck with.

Comment: By the way, you might be interested in [What to do with the \[google-meet\] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426507/1595451).

Comment: Is there an effort to remove things that are related to programming but not directly talking about code? For example, adding this functionality via extension implies that coding is going on somewhere. Many thousands of questions here are of that form. If there's a better Stack site to move this to then I'd be glad to do so. My expectation was that someone would chime in to indicate a general coding approach to implement this, or they'd suggest a tool (open source) that already does so.

Comment: That is something to ask on [meta] or [meta.se].